# How to reorder some rows in specfic orders in pandas python

Tags: machine-learning, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:

```
     A    B
0    2    3
1    2    5
2    1    7
3    1    8
```

And I want to re-order it like this in a fast and efficient way:

```
     A    B
0    1    8
1    1    7
2    2    5
3    2    3
```

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

According that your DataFrame is df, just use

```
df.sort_values(by='B')
```

Comment: `df.sort_values(by=['A','B'])` looks to me like the OP wants to sort both columns

Answer (score 0):

You could try the implementation given on this page.using the sort_values function. 
Assuming your data is stored in a data frame you can use `df.sort_values(by="B")
For a better understanding go to the following link

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Please check it out!

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @StephenRauch My bad!. Thought it was simple enough to understand based on the link. Anyway changed!